# Run device build on simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Is it possible to run the .app file build for "Device" configuration to run on "Simulator"
I have tried to figure out few Info.plist entries which differ for simulator and device configuration.
So,
1) Is it possible to install device app on simulator
2) What are the changes needed to do so?

Comment: It's not possible. There are different core architectures - `armv` and `i386`

Comment: Thanks beryllium I've used lipo and libtool before to change architecture of framework but can I use same or others to do the same for .app file?

Comment: @SGadhvi No. The app has to be recompiled from the source files.

Answer (score 2):

No it's not possible. The app for the device is compiled to run on a different processor architecture than you mac.

Answer (score 2):

No This is not possible. The device build is compiled for the ARM processor, while the simulator build can only run x86 code.